# How to downscale the pixel values in UWP App (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, pixel

I built a UWP App based on the Squeeze Net example provided in the repository (C#) that uses a Deep Learning model (ONNX) for image classification. I have built the deep learning model in PyTorch where the pixel values of the image have been scaled down from the range [0, 255] to [0, 1] and then normalized with channel wise (RGB) standard deviation and mean. So, this model expects the pixel values other than [0, 255] range.

But in the UWP App, I'm unable to perform this downscaling of the pixel values before binding the inputs to the model. I have searched the SoftwareBitmap class but couldn't find a way to perform this downscaling operation. Any help would be very very appreciated.

I need this operation somewhere in between these lines of code.

```
await LoadModel();

            // Trigger file picker to select an image file
            var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            outputTextBlock.Text = $"The selected Image: {file.Name}";

            SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // Create the decoder from the stream 
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

                PixelDataProvider random = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                // byte[] pD =  random.DetachPixelData();
                //await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync("path/file.ext", pD);
                // System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path/file.ext", pD);
                // byteData.Text = $"{pD}";


                // Get the SoftwareBitmap representation of the file in BGRA8 format
                softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
                softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
            }

            var streamD = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
            await imageSource.SetSourceAsync(streamD);

            selectedImage.Source = imageSource;

            // Display the image
            //SoftwareBitmapSource imageSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
            //await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);
            //selectedImage.Source = imageSource;

            // Encapsulate the image within a VideoFrame to be bound and evaluated
            VideoFrame inputWoodImage = VideoFrame.CreateWithSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);

            await EvaluateVideoFrameAsync(inputWoodImage);
```

Comment: Add the control into `Canvas`. Bind the `Height` and `Width` of that control and you can adjust the size.

Comment: I am confused with your question, what do you want? What is the mean of 'downscale'? Do you just want to decrease the quality of  the image?

Comment: Hey, when I want to use the Deep Learning Model I built in Pytorch in a UWP app. An image's pixel values that are initially in the range [0, 255] are first converted to a tensor ranging from [0, 1]. This is done by dividing each pixel value by 255 to bring it down to the range [0, 1]. And then this tensor is normalized with a mean and standard deviation for each channel (RGB). I'm able to downscale the pixel values from range [0, 255] to [0, 1] but not able to further normalize these byte data type values using mean and standard deviation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a repost of this thread here that contains some answers and is more actual:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/issues/22